# How to improve performance on a SQL database table that has 60 million rows

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, index

I have a table that has 60 million rows in a Postgresql database.

Table is as follows:

```
id varchar PK
cutomerId Integer
orderId Integer
modified timestamp.
```

Now I want to create a summary of customer and number of orders on a particular day for example

```
SELECT customerId, COUNT(orderId) 
FROM orders o  
WHERE DATE(o.modified) = '2023-04-27' GROUP by customerId
```

This takes up to 5 minutes to return in SQL query UI.

Is there any way I can speed this up?

here is my explain analyze:

```
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=778305.85..778574.65 rows=1061 width=12) (actual time=43412.506..43435.712 rows=1089 loops=1)
  Group Key: customerId
  Buffers: shared hit=1414708 read=576689
  I/O Timings: read=123468.547
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=778305.85..778553.43 rows=2122 width=12) (actual time=43412.472..43435.024 rows=3267 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=1414708 read=576689
        I/O Timings: read=123468.547
        ->  Sort  (cost=777305.82..777308.47 rows=1061 width=12) (actual time=43341.758..43341.892 rows=1089 loops=3)
              Sort Key: customerId
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 100kB
              Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 100kB
              Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 100kB
              Buffers: shared hit=1414708 read=576689
              I/O Timings: read=123468.547
              ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=777241.89..777252.50 rows=1061 width=12) (actual time=43340.904..43341.102 rows=1089 loops=3)
                    Group Key: customerId
                    Buffers: shared hit=1414694 read=576689
                    I/O Timings: read=123468.547
                    ->  Parallel Index Scan using orders_idx on orders o  (cost=0.43..770040.97 rows=1440183 width=8) (actual time=0.205..42743.905 rows=1097188 loops=3)
                          Index Cond: ((modified >= '2022-02-16'::date) AND (modified < '2022-02-17'::date))
                          Buffers: shared hit=1414694 read=576689
                          I/O Timings: read=123468.547
Planning Time: 10.171 ms
Execution Time: 43436.656 ms
```

Comment: What indexes are currently defined on your table? What does the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` say for this query? Also are you missing a `GROUP BY customerId` clause?

Comment: replace `DATE(o.modified) = '2023-04-27'` with range condition: `o.modified >= '2023-04-27'::date and o.modified < '2023-04-28'::date`, check that helpful index exists

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: @J.D. updated my question with execution plan... have added an index on modified

Comment: @user1555190 are you missing a `GROUP BY customerId` clause?

Comment: @J.D. no the group by is set... in the explain you can see the Group Key

Comment: Yea but that's non-standard syntax then, which leaves it to the default logic of the database engine. You should explicitly use a `GROUP BY` clause, generally speaking. Doubt that'll make a difference with your performance issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need an index on `date(modified)` for that.

A better solution would be to have an index on `modified` and change the query to

```
SELECT customerId, COUNT(orderId) 
FROM orders o  
WHERE o.modified >= '2023-04-27'::date AND o.modified < '2023-04-27'::date + 1
GROUP by customerId;
```

To improve the speed of the query, you can create a covering index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON orders (modified) INCLUDE (customerid, orderid);

VACUUM orders;
```

The `VACUUM` will update the visibility map, so that the index-only scan can become fast. Make sure that the table is vacuumed often enough.

Comment: i created the index... the query i still taking up 50 seconds

Comment: I don't believe that you created the correct index. Can you show the output of `\d orders` in `psql`?

Comment: CREATE INDEX orders_modified_idx ON public.orders USING btree (modified);
I just got the sql for the index

Comment: Perhaps you misconfigured something. Can you add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)` output for the query to the question?

Comment: yes see above main question... just added explain analyze... the table does have 8GB of data.

Comment: I don't want `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)`. I want `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)`.

Comment: I have done EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS), however my sql client wont allow settings... could be due to postgresql being an aws rds instance?

Comment: Thanks. The question is if your *server* allows it. Perhaps you are using an old version of PostgreSQL that does not support it. The only explanation I can think of why PostgreSQL does not use the index is that some PostgreSQL parameters are mis-configured. Which parameters have non-default settings?

Comment: @ Laurenz Albe
Thanks for that. I looked at it again. And have got the index working i think.
In the EXPLAIN it now shows index scan. Does this help?

Comment: I don't think you are telling the whole truth. Your previous execution plans that used sequential scans found zero matching rows, while the new plan finds 3 million matching rows. You must be using different data (and perhaps different index definitions).

Comment: Yes i ran this on my pre-production db. I had two tabs client open, one for "dev" and pre-production. So my previous plans was from dev, got little confusing and the index was on preprod. When you said it was misconfigured... i looked at which db i was using... My bad!

Comment: any ideas? I have tried playing around with indexes. Cant get the time to drop?

Comment: I have edited my answer with an idea how to speed up the index scan.

Comment: That made is super fast 911.924 ms.. what does vacuum actually do? do re organise the data?

Comment: It updates the *visibility map*, so that you get a real index scan. PostgreSQL's architecture makes index-only scans difficult.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is [tuning your Postgres](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server) server, particularly the memory configuration settings that handle how the database cluster handles indexes. Out of the box, the Postgres config file is set up to allow the software to run on a very minimal computing environment. By understanding how Postgres uses  resources you can customize your set-up for you hardware and optimize you performance.

Another, more basic step would be to run [the `EXPLAIN` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) on your query and see how your query planner is using your indexes. If you post the output of the `EXPLAIN` command here you'll likely get more helpful responses.

Comment: I have done that. Thanks